# Angular 4 Can't resolve all parameters for Service: ([object Object], ?)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, dependency-injection, webpack-dev-server

I tryied all variants from SO and github issues.

Trouble: I got custom module from private npm repository. This module made by angular-cli and publish by ng-packagr.

My project is built using @ngtools/webpack. And just code:

app.module.ts

```
import { MyHeaderModule } from 'my-header/src/app/modules/my-header/my-header.module';
import { PORTAL_URL, MAINHOME_URL, CURRENT_USER_LOGIN } from 'my-header/src/app/modules/my-base/base.service';

function initConfigFactory() {
   return Promise.resolve("login");
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(RoutesConfig), MyHeaderModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: (<any> [ AppComponent ]).concat(Object.values(Components), Object.values(Directives), Object.values(Pipes)),
  providers: (<any> Object.values(Services)).concat([
    DatePipe,
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "ru-RU" },
    { provide: PORTAL_URL, useValue: environment.portalUrl },
    { provide: MAINHOME_URL, useValue: environment.mainHomeUrl },
    { provide: CURRENT_USER_LOGIN, useFactory: initConfigFactory, multi: true }
  ]),
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

navigation.service.ts

```
import { BaseService, PORTAL_URL, MAINHOME_URL, CURRENT_USER_LOGIN } from '../my-base/base.service';
@Injectable()
export class NavigationService extends BaseService {

    protected serviceUrl = this.mainHomeUrl + '/api/v1.0/navigation';

    constructor(protected http: Http,
        @Inject(PORTAL_URL) public portalUrl: string,
        @Inject(MAINHOME_URL) public mainHomeUrl: string,
        @Inject(CURRENT_USER_LOGIN) public userLogin: any
    ) {
        super(http, portalUrl, mainHomeUrl);
    }
    ...
}
```

base.service.ts

```
export const PORTAL_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('');
export const MAINHOME_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('');
export const CURRENT_USER_LOGIN = new InjectionToken<Function>(null);

@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseService {...}
```

Thats give me

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NavigationService: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?)

Comment: It would *seem* that not having the `CURRENT_USER_LOGIN` listed in the providers in the *app.module* is part of the issue. I have never tried to provide a Function using the container, so I don't know if that would work. Are you providing `CURRENT_USER_LOGIN` in another module?

Comment: I tried this variant. The error is the same

Comment: Well, I'm not so sure whether an InjectionToken can contain null when <T> is defined as Function. What happens to your Error if you replace export const CURRENT_USER_LOGIN = new InjectionToken<Function>(null); by export const CURRENT_USER_LOGIN = new InjectionToken<string>(''); instead?

Comment: I can try this, but can't add this fix to this module repo. All other projects with this module have not this error. I think that the point is that my project does not use angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { MyHeaderModule } from 'my-header/src/app/modules/my-header/my-header.module';
import { PORTAL_URL, MAINHOME_URL } from 'my-header/src/app/modules/my-base/base.service';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(RoutesConfig), MyHeaderModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: (<any> [ AppComponent ]).concat(Object.values(Components), Object.values(Directives), Object.values(Pipes)),
  providers: (<any> Object.values(Services)).concat([
    DatePipe,
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "ru-RU" },
    { provide: PORTAL_URL, useValue: environment.portalUrl },
    { provide: MAINHOME_URL, useValue: environment.mainHomeUrl },
    // You are missing this line right here:
    { provide: CURRENT_USER_LOGIN, useValue: environment.currentUserLogin },
  ]),
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Nope, I already checked this option and it did not give results. The error is the same.